How to handle file names with double quotes in a Bash script
I have a Bash script that reveals the most recent file in the ~/Downloads directory. However, the script currently fails when the file name contains double quotes ("). I need to modify the script to handle such file names correctly.
Here's the script:
# Set the path to the Downloads directory
DOWNLOADS="$HOME/Downloads"

# Use 'find' to search for files recursively within Downloads
RECENT=$(find "$DOWNLOADS" -type f -exec mdls -name kMDItemPath -name kMDItemDateAdded {} + | \
sed 'N;s/\n//' | \
awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " substr($0,index($0,$7))}' | \
sort -r | \
cut -d'"' -f2 | \
head -n1)

# Open the most recently added file
open -R "$RECENT"

And I already know that the awk line will output something like this:
2024-04-25 19:58:32 "/System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Downloads/Noto_Sans/NotoSans-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf"
2024-04-25 19:58:32 "/System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Downloads/Noto_Sans/NotoSans-Italic-"VariableFont_wdth","wght".ttf"
2024-04-25 19:58:32 "/System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Downloads/Noto_Sans/static/NotoSans_SemiCondensed-LightItalic.ttf" 

As you can see, some file names contain double quotes, which causes issues with the cut command since it treats " as a delimiter.
How can I modify the script to handle file names with double quotes (and any other special character) correctly?
Any help will be appreciated!
I tried modifying the delimiter used and was able to get the file path as a full, but the path containing the double quote still wouldn't be treated as a valid path.

Wouldn't it fail as well, if you had filenames with newlines? The problem seems to me, that your mdls seems to be designed to work only for files with names from a certain set of characters. For your concrete case, I wouldn't use cut to extract the filename. You just extract everything between the first and the last double-quote. How about using grep -oP?

Since the prefix of each line seems to be constant in size, you could also drop from each line the first 21 characters, and the last one, and you should be left then with the filename.
